# Maximum of the convex linear combination of continuous functions on a compact domain

Tags: optimization, continuity, convex-analysis, compactness

I can't figure out a way to prove, or disprove, the following statement: let $(f_i(x))_{i\in I}, I=\{1,...,n\}$ be a collections of real valued, continuous functions defined on a compact domain, i.e. $\forall i \in I, f_i:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, let us assume that each functions has exactly one maximum. Define $g(x):=\sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i \cdot f_i(x)$, with $\omega_i \in [0,1], \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i=1$. $\forall i \in I$, let $x^*_i= arg max_{x\in[0,1]}f_i(x)$. I suspect that $argmax_{x\in[0,1]}g(x)\subseteq [min\{(x^*_i)_{i \in I}\}, max\{(x^*_i)_{i \in I}\}]$ but I can't find a way to prove it. Can someone help me?

Comment: It is not true. Take, for example, all the $f_i$ constant and $x_i^* = 1/2$ for every $i$.

Answer (score 1):

For $0\leq a < b \leq 1$, let $t_{a,b}$ be the "triangular" function such that
$t_{a,b}(x) = 0$ if $x\leq a$ or $x\geq b$, $t_{a,b}(\frac{a+b}{2}) = 1$.
Let
$$
f_1(x) = 4 t_{0, 1/4}(x) + 2 t_{3/4, 1}(x), \qquad
f_2(x) = - 4 t_{0, 1/4}(x) + t_{1/4, 1/2}(x),
$$
so that $x_1^* = 1/8$, $x_2^* = 3/8$.
Choosing $\omega_1 = \omega_2 = 1/4$ it holds that
$g(x) = t_{3/4, 1}(x) + \frac{1}{2} \, t_{1/4, 1/2}(x)$, hence $\text{argmax} g = \{7/8\}$.

Comment: Makes sense. What if we restrict our attention to strictly positive functions?

Comment: Add $5$ to $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: Right hahaha, thank you!